# Material arc Movement animation with jquery

Tags: jquery, material-design

Following the [Material Design Guidelines of movement](https://material.io/guidelines/motion/movement.html), how can I animate it using jQuery?
I have this image with position absolute and I want to move it across the window using [this](https://storage.googleapis.com/material-design/publish/material_v_11/assets/0B14F_FSUCc01R1pOdFdNUm0yOFk/ShiftWithin_01_Upward_Do_v3.mp4) arc movement (or obviously the downward when needed), how can i make it?

Answer (score 0):

I keept trying to make it and created the following function:

```
(function ($) {
        $.fn.materialMovement = function (endX, endY, time, params, pro, complete) {
            time = time === null || typeof time === "undefined" ? 350 : time;
            params = params === null || typeof params === "undefined" ? {opacity: 1} : params;
            var el = $(this);
            var startX = parseInt($(el).css("left")), startY = parseInt($(el).css("top"));
            var diffLeft = endX - startX, diffTop = endY - startY;
            var down = endY > startY;
            $(el).animate(params, {
                progress: function (a, p, c) {
                    var top = down ? startY + (diffTop * p) : startY + ((diffTop * p) * p);
                    var left = down ? startX + (diffLeft * p) * p : startX + diffLeft * p;
                    $(el).css({left: left, top: top});
                    if ($.isFunction(pro)) {
                        pro(a, p, c);
                    }
                },
                easing: "swing",
                duration: time,
                complete: function () {
                    if ($.isFunction(complete)) {
                        complete();
                    }
                }
            });
        };
    }(jQuery));
```

But, when it deals with change of size, the animation is a lot different than the one without change of size...